# How can we maintain the OidcProvider in react-router 4.0?

Tags: reactjs, identityserver3, react-router-v4, openid-connect

We are going to change our react-router from version 3 to 4.0, earlier we are maintaining the redux-store and passing the store to the component as:-

```
   <Provider store={store}>
        <OidcProvider store={store} userManager={userManager}>
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
              <Router history={browserHistory} children={routes} />
            </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </OidcProvider>
      </Provider>
```

**How can I use the same OidcProvider in our react-router 4.0**? Please assist me.